# Custom UITableviewcell updates in hidden cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have used custom UITableViewCell. I have added a Gesture in it for swipe option, I have 20 cells in my `tableView`. If I swipe my first cell and scroll means my 11th cell also updated into my first cell value.

the following is my code snipet.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellId”];
     [cell setRequestCellDelegate:self];
    [cell.swipeLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.swipeLeft.delegate = self;
    cell.swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    cell.indexpath = indexPath;
    [cell.swipeRight addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    cell.swipeRight.delegate = self;
    cell.swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    cell.tableHoldButtn.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Please help to find the solution for this.

Comment: is there any specific reason for using gesture??

Comment: Yes, used to edit the cell.

Answer (score 1):

This is happenning because as soon as your first swiped cell goes off the screen it's being put into queue for reuse. Then when your 10th cell should come on the screen it's not being created but rather 1st cell is being reused. And since you have swiped it, it will be dequeued in exact same state as it left the screen.

You should track changes in table view controller which cell should be swiped and restore that state in your cellForIndexPath data source method.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your explanation. If i use global variable for table cell which cell should be affect , the error will clear right ?

Comment: Using global variable is a very bad idea. Keep an array of swiped index paths that is stored in an instance of view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use tableView delegate methods instead on applying gesture. you can use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Additionally you can also customise the edit button appearance by:

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thank you for you response , i have added lot of thing using Gesture, so if i change this it will affect my all other functionality, so need solution for this what i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringwithFormat:"%ld",indexPath.row]];
```

reuse Identifier change to the string  of indexPath.row

I hope my experiment can help you

Comment: Hi,I used your code but i got the following error.Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:7524

Comment: you regist cell ues a fixed reuseId,it must have problem,see my new answer

Comment: Yes , i used ur updated code, now its not displaying my table cells, its showing blank Table(white ).

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath this method is run, the cell is nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118645/discussion-between-augustin-a-and-wg-hjl).

Answer (score 0):

**note:** do not register cell  in other place,remove register cell in  other place (maybe in viewdidLoad )

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)
//    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellId”];
// need not register cell  in other ,like viewdidLoad
    CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath.row]];

     if (!cell) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath.row]];
         cell.selectionStyle =     UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     }

     [cell setRequestCellDelegate:self];
     [cell.swipeLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
     cell.tag = indexPath.row;
     cell.swipeLeft.delegate = self;
     cell.swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
     cell.indexpath = indexPath;
     [cell.swipeRight addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
     cell.swipeRight.delegate = self;
     cell.swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
     cell.tableHoldButtn.tag = indexPath.row;

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];

     if (!cell) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
         cell.selectionStyle =     UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     }    I used your code with updated, i got empty cell , means it shows white table view.

Comment: Means cell not displaying any data.